# How to avoid repeating the same 'else' statement in multiple nested if/else?

Tags: if-statement, nested, nested-if

In the code below, 'else' is same for all 'if' statements? Is there a way to have just one 'else' statement, rather than repeating the same code in all 'if' statement blocks for 'else' statement?

Here's example:

```
if condition A == "Yes":
    print("A")
    if condition B == "Yes":
        print("B")
    else:
        print("D")
        if condition C =="Yes":
            print("C")
        else:
            print("D")
else:
    print("D")
```

[Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhXKO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of nested if else, you can use a `guard` type statement. `guard` is popular in case of nested if-else and provides a clean code.

Guard statement tries to element the else cases first. You know we write else cases to perform deviated paths. So what if we remove the
deviated paths first.

For example, if you have

```
if condition A == "Yes":
    print("A")
    if condition B == "Yes":
        print("B")
    else:
        print("D")
        if condition C =="Yes":
            print("C")
        else:
            print("D")
else:
    print("D")
```

Now I can formatting the following

```
// 1 
if condiation A == "No" {
    print("D")
    return 
}

// 2
if condition B == "Yes" {
    print("B")
    return 
}

if condition C == "No" {
   print("D")
   return 
}

print("C")
```

For more follow the link: - [Youtube](https://youtu.be/ZzwWWut_ibU)

Comment: I'm struggling to incorporate guard type statement. Here's code with if/else  and nested statements. I have also added flowchart link in original question. https://github.com/manbirs/PythonLearning/blob/de63a9d99849fa8045f21db9379fa653639815a5/B3:%20if%20else,%20nested.

Comment: Yes, I understand the guard-type intentions are hard to find at first. But consider the else cases first and try to return. We know that if `if` is wrong, then definitely go to the `else` case. And by the way else is basically an exit case. So mark the exit routes first, return them earlier before executing the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You look like in a nested testing sequence

You test A
if A ok, you test B
if B ok you test C

if any test fail you print D

so ...
you eitheir leave the testing sequence test everything print all Yes result
or print D if any test fail (wich look like a big ERROR message)

or
you keep the ugly if else sequence

Comment: Newbie with python here... So, if I want to leave sequence in between (assuming condition B is not OK, so go to D), how to achieve it without adding same else statement (D) in each If statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you go for testing everything
you can create a function

```py
def TestThis(Value, id):
    if value == "Yes":
        print(id)
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

and call it like this:

```py
if TestThis(A, "A") == 0:
    integrity = 1
elif TestThis(B, "B") == 0:
    integrity = 1
elif TestThis(C, "C") == 0:
    integrity = 1
if integrity == 1:
    print("D")
```

And I'm pretty sure you can find a way to finally get your sequence testing.

Edited to create that sequential testing that was the aim from the start